# Increasing available memory to Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

To increase the MAX available memory I use :

```
export SPARK_MEM=1 g
```

Alternatively I can use

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
             .setMaster("local")
             .setAppName("My application")
             .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

The process I'm running requires much more than 1g. I would like to use 20g but I just have 8g of RAM available. Can disk memory be augmented with RAM memory as part of a Spark job, if so how is this achieved ?

Is there a Spark doc which describes how to distribute jobs to multiple Spark installations ?

For spark configuration I'm using all defaults (specified at http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/configuration.html) except for what I have specified above.
I have a single machine instance with following :

```
CPU : 4 cores
RAM : 8GB
HD : 40GB
```

Update :

I think this is the doc I'm looking for : http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/spark-standalone.html

Comment: What do you mean by _"how to distribute jobs to multiple Spark installations"_? If you have a single machine, I assume you have a single Spark installation?

Comment: @Daniel Darabos yes I have a single Spark installation running on one machine. But because I am experiencing memory exceptions I want to distribute the computation to multiple machines. Does Spark not need to be installed on multiple machines to allow distributed computation ?

Comment: Oh, you're on the right track then! The documentation you linked has exactly what you need to do. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to solve a problem on a single computer, I do not think it is practical to use Spark. The point of Spark is that it provides a way to distribute computation across multiple machines, especially in cases where the data does not fit on a single machine.

That said, just set `spark.executor.memory` to `20g` to get 20 GB of virtual memory. Once the physical memory is exhausted, swap will be used instead. If you have enough swap configured, you will be able to make use of 20 GB. But your process will most likely slow down to a crawl when it starts swapping.

Answer (score 12):

If your job does not fit into memory Spark will automatically spill to disk - **you do NOT need to setup swap** - i.e. Daniel's answer is a bit inaccurate.  You can configure what kind of processing will and will not spill to disk using the configuration settings: http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/configuration.html

Also it IS a good idea to use Spark on a single machine, because it means if you need your application to scale, you will get scaling for free - the same code you write to run 1-node will work N-node.  Of course if your data is never expected to grow, then yes, stick with pure Scala.

Use `spark.shuffle.spill` to control whether shuffles spill, and read the "persistence" documentation to control how RDD caching spills http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I don't get why someone would want to use Scala if they are not using Spark though :).

Comment: IMHO Scala is the future dude ;)

Comment: what's exactly the one configuration we should modify to force the spill to disk? when my RAM (32GB) is full and my SWAP (4GB), the server crashes and becomes unresponsive, so I don't believe it's working as you mentioned in your post unless I change some parameter (that I can't find). THanks!

Comment: @Stephane Use `spark.shuffle.spill` to control whether shuffles spill, and read the "persistence" documentation to control how RDD caching spills http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence